# What are the maximal subgroups of a finite abelian group in terms of characters?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, harmonic-analysis, maximal-subgroup

Let $(G,+)$ be a finite abelian group with neutre $0$.
A maximal subgroup of $G$ is a proper subgroup $H$ such that no other proper subgroup $K$ of $G$ contains $H$ strictly.
We know that characters of $G$ (i.e. morphisms $G \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$) are roots of unity and take their values in $\mathbb{U}_e$ where $e$ is the exponent of $G$.
But I would like to demonstrate that the maximal subgroups of $G$ are the kernels of the characters $\chi$ whose image is a subgroup of the form $\mathbb{U}_p$ with $p$ a prime.
I don’t understand the link between the prime $p$ and the maximal property of the subgroup.
Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: The maximal subgroups all have prime index. For each subgroup, take the action on the cosets. Its image will be cyclic of irime order and thus can be interpreted as a linear character.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: ahulpke: since $G$ is abelian, any subgroup $H$ is normal and then you consider the action $G \times G/H \longrightarrow G/H$ whose image is a group of prime order $p$ dividing the order of $G$ and therefore cyclic. Is that right ?

Comment: Yes (padding to reach 15 characters)